# How to apply function to each element of a 2d tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking for a way to apply a tensorflow op to each element of a 2d tensor e.g.

```
input = tf.Variable([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
# final result should look like: 
# [[myCustomOp(1.0), myCustomOp(2.0)]), [myCustomOp(3.0), myCustomOp(4.0)]]
```

Comment: you can apply any operation on each element like myCustomOp( input [0,0])

Comment: I need to get the whole tensor affected (see the desirable result)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
  def myOp(t):
    return t+1
  shape = tf.shape(input)
  elems = tf.reshape(input, [-1])
  res = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t: myOp(t), elems=elems)
  res = tf.reshape(res, shape)
```